# Multiples arrays into one

Tags: php, sql, arrays, cakephp

I have a SQL query that gets me results from different tables. I get my results like this:

```
\app\View\Followings\index.ctp (line 14)
array(
    'Following' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '3',
        'follower_id' => '2'
    ),
    'Blogging' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'value' => 'What is zyzz about ?',
            'user_id' => '3',
            'created' => '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
        )
    ),
    'Photo' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'value' => 'zyzz.jpg',
            'user_id' => '3',
            'created' => '2014-02-12 00:00:00'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'value' => 'zyzz2.jpg',
            'user_id' => '3',
            'created' => '2015-05-07 00:00:00'
        )
    )
)
\app\View\Followings\index.ctp (line 14)
array(
    'Following' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'user_id' => '4',
        'follower_id' => '2'
    ),
    'Blogging' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'value' => 'lolpl',
            'user_id' => '4',
            'created' => '2013-12-01 00:00:00'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'value' => 'Do you even lift brah ?',
            'user_id' => '4',
            'created' => '2015-06-18 00:00:00'
        )
    ),
    'Photo' => array()
)
```

My question is how to get in one single array with "Users" mixed and the "value" ordered by id (or by date)? Thank you.

The controller:

```
public function index(){

    $followings = $this->Following->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Following.follower_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
        'recursive' => 1,
    ));


    $this->set('followings', $followings); 

}
```

Comment: Post more code please, start with code in your Controller that prepares for and performs the queries that populate these arrays.

Comment: I added it to the orignal post

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first trying to use CakePHP's built-in options for the find() method to get the desired results. I don't understand what you mean by having the results with users "mixed", but making use of 'order' and 'group' in your find may do the trick.

For CakePHP 2.x:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

If you still can't get the results structured exactly the way you want, you can always build a new array by iterating over the $followings result inside the controller and then do the `$this->set` using the new array instead of with $followings.